# submit file with dropzonejs

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone

I have form with input fields. now i add file input field and i would like to use **[dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com)**

I would like to submit the files (multiple) **only** when i post the form.

the preview of the files are good, but when i post the form i don't get the files info

```
<?PHP
if ($_POST)
    print_r($_FILES);
?>

<!-- Dropzone.js -->
<script src="vendors/dropzone/dist/dropzone.js"></script>

<form method='post' action='index.php?page=tktSubmit&amp;act=submit' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

    <input type='text' name='title'  value="<?PHP echo $_POST['tktTitle'] ?>" class="form-control" />
    <textarea name="msgText" class="form-control" ><?PHP echo nl2br ($_POST['msgText']) ?></textarea>

        <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Attached File:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="dropzone"></div>
        </div>  

</form>
```

Comment: not even close.... @pedram

Comment: Maybe this answer could help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631659/dropzone-js-form-submit-not-sending-file

Comment: @HastaDhana - thanks, but no, it's not helping...